# Ternary Operator Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, conditional-operator

I want to convert this if, else-if, can someone help me out please?

```
if (condition1)
    response.Redirect(" some link");
else if (condition2)
    response.Redirect("link 2");
```

I want convert above statement,but showing error at the end, required ":". Any other way i can use this?

```
LinkPurchase.PostBackUrl =((Condition)?string.Format("some link"):  
                        (condition2)?string.Format("link 2));
```

Comment: What does `Response.End` return?

Comment: what is wrong with simple if's ?

Comment: "I want to convert the Conditional Code to ternary".  Trust me, no you don't.

Comment: I'd write this as an answer, but new answers are locked... `var redirect = condition1 ? "some link" : (condition2 ? "link2") : null; if(redirect!=null)response.Redirect(redirect);`

Comment: @dss539 That could be made to work! However the `()` inside your first expression are misplaced.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks, unfortunately I can't edit the comment for some reason

Comment: Guys thanks for your comments, i found the solution. It was simple, i added ":null" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rewrite that to the `?:` operator.

You have an `if`-`else if`, not just an `if`-`else`.

Besides, you do not pick up the return values from the `Redirect` calls.

The usual case where you do want to rewrite to the `?:` operator is:

```
if (condition)
  something = Abc();
else
  something = Xyz();
```

where it is natural to use instead:

```
something = condition ? Abc() : Xyz();
```

Comment: He *could*.  It almost certainly wouldn't be a good idea, but it's absolutely possible.

Comment: @Servy I wonder how? Are you going to answer something like `(condition1 ? () => response.Redirect(" some link") : condition2 ? () => response.Redirect("link 2") : (Action)(() => { }))();` (I made it!)?

Comment: That's certainly one way, yes.  Not the only way of course, but you've now successfully proved your own answer wrong.

Comment: @Servy Nothing can prove a perfect answer wrong, not even the comments of its own author.

Comment: I'll be sure to test that theory out when I actually find a perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.

There are other answers here that inform you that the ?: operator needs the "else" part, so yes, the first problem is that you're missing that.

However, `Response.Redirect` doesn't return anything, so you cannot do this *even with the else part*.

`?:` is an expression, you cannot write statements (easily) with this.

Stick with the `if`-statements.